# Canvas rectangle background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, background-image

I want to set background image to my rectangle in the canvas.
So far i've done this.

```
var img = new Image()
    img.src = //Source of an image.
var newPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = newPattern;
```

And it works, but the problem is, that it applies the image to the canvas, not to the rectangle.

And whenever I change the position of the rectangle, the image remains in the same position.

Can anybody suggest how to fix this, so the image'd be attached to the rectangle.

Comment: yes `createPattern` uses the whole canvas as destination and if no `transform` are provided (through the `CanvasPattern.setTransform` method), it will default to the top-left corner. But since you want a `no-repeat`, why don't you simply use `drawImage` ? (PS: don't forget to wait for your image has loaded before doing anything with it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But no `drawImage` is not working properly in this case, I want image to appear only in rectangle or any other shape that may be (**circle**, **triangle**, **square**, etc ), as the rectangle would be the mask but the image would be attached to it, `cratePattern` works as mask, but image is not attached to it.

Comment: then what you want is [`ctx.clip()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) https://jsfiddle.net/6cmquz58/

Comment: And if I get it right `setTransform`, affects the shape (rectangle) itself, and not the background.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Kaiido .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only draw the image within a specified rectangle you can do something like this.

```
context.rect(x, y, width, height);
context.clip();
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

This creates a rectangle at (x, y) with size (width, height) which is used for all future calls to the context. If you want to stop the clipping you will need to add a

```
context.save();
```

before the code above and then a

```
context.restore();
```

after you have drawn the image.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbw1vqse/1/)

Edit: updated to rect

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am really new to canvas, maybe because of that I couldn't apply your suggestions correctly. I will go through a couple of Canvas courses and will try to make this steps again. whatever for a better view I'll put jsFiddle of what I got. _every Circle should have it's own image_ [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drewrg/nrq6u7qe/)

Comment: I've updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nrq6u7qe/3/), it draws a circle and an image (had to use the jsfiddle logo due to cross-origin restrictions). The image is clipped using the circle. You should compare it to your original fiddle. The function with the important stuff is the render function. To get the fiddle to work you might need to press run because of the image loading.

Comment: `fillRect` is a very special command which will create a unique path, out of the ones currently drawn on the context, and can't be used for `clip`. What you want is `rect()` or any other Path Command

Comment: Thank you @DavidHartley that helped a a lot.